# Changing the attribute of an instance object of a class that's declared in another package and whose variable is constructed by its parent class

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, 2d

Ok, so I have a bunch of classes and I'd like to rotate an object which has an object shape, which is a 2d array and that's constructed in the parent class of the object class. I want to change the attribute (shape) in the method rotate() which calls the method multiplyarray that does the rotation by changing the shape. However, I realized that I don't have access to shape, or at least I don't know how to change it. I don't think the parent class has a public setShape method. Anyway here's the code:

```
public static int[][] multiplyMatrix(int[][] m1) {

    int[][] m2 = { { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, };

    int[][] result = new int[4][4];

    // multiply
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                if (m1[i][k] * m2[k][j] > 0) {
                    result[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    result[i][j] = 0;
                }

    return result;
}
```

the rotate method:

```
synchronized void rotateClockwise() {
    currentPiece.shape = multiplyMatrix(shape);

    //gives me an error
    updateLocation();
}
```

the constructor (all three methods are in the same class):

```
    public Piece(int shape[][]) {
    super(shape);
    currentX = 7;
    currentY = 2;
    updateLocation();
}
```

this method is in another class and it contains the instance object whose attribute i want to modify:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    int key = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (key) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP: // up arrow
    case KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP:
        currentPiece.rotateCounterclockwise();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: // down arrow
    case KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN:
        currentPiece.rotateClockwise();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: // left arrow
    case KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT:
        currentPiece.moveLeft();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: // right arrow
    case KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT:
        currentPiece.moveRight();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: //  space bar
        currentPiece.drop();
    }
}
```

createPiece method (I want to access the shape attribute):

```
public static Piece createPiece() {
    int[][] s = SHAPES[(int) (Math.random() * SHAPES.length)];
    switch ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    default:
        return new Piece(s);
    }
}
```

entire code can be found here (without certain modifications):

http://mathcs.slu.edu/~fritts/cse131/labs/lab9/index.html

Update:

I found out that super calls this constructor in Grid:

```
public Grid(int[][] contents) {
    this.contents = contents;
    Dimension d = new Dimension(getColumns()*Tetris.SQUARE_SIZE,
                                getRows()*Tetris.SQUARE_SIZE);
    setSize(d);
    setPreferredSize(d);
    setOpaque(false);
}
```

Now, I tried this:

```
synchronized void rotateClockwise() {
Grid.contents = multiplyMatrix(Grid.contents);
updateLocation();

}
```

It gives me:

non-static method getContents() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I think that much will depend on code and program structure that you've not yet revealed to us.

Comment: the biggest problem I have is with the object currentPieces and the variable I need to access. I successfully implemented moveRight moveLeft and moveDown, but rotate is too difficult to implement, because I don't know how to access the variables and Objects. I tried using getters and setters, but to not avail.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us the code of the superclass, but one approach might be to create a mirror of the `shape` field in the subclass, override the getter and add a setter; e.g.

```
  public class Super {
      private Shape shape;
      public Super(Shape shape) { this.shape = shape; }
      public Shape getShape() { return this.shape; }
  }

  public class Sub extends Super {
      private Shape myShape;

      public Sub(Shape shape) {
          super(shape);
          this.myShape = shape;
      }

      @Override
      public Shape getShape() { return this.myShape; }

      public void setShape(Shape shape) { this.myShape = shape; }
  }
```

This approach will only work if `Super` is designed to allow this.  In particular, `Super` must use `getShape()` to fetch the `Shape` value.

(There are *horrible* workarounds if `Super` is not designed to support extension here, but I'm sure that your teacher is not expecting you to use them here ....)

Comment: I am doing this on my own and I just realized that the super calls the constructor in Grid. I am trying to modify Grid.contents but I can't. Please help me. I really need to do this. This is not an assignment.

Comment: I don't care if they are horrible. I just want to get it working.

Comment: Not an assignment? It [looks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14867570/230513) like an assignment.

Comment: It's not, because I wasn't given that assignment and googled for a tetris tutorial.

Comment: Assigned: Monday, April 18
Due: Friday, April 29 (but may be turned in until Tuesday, May 3 without penalty) --We are in February

Comment: I did try adding those 2 classes, but it didn't compile. Shape is an attribute of Piece.

Comment: Like can you tell me if I can change contents instead of shape and whether I need to change the shape of the instance object or just the variable shape and tell me if I can implement it without making a new class, because it didn't seem that new classes should be created for this and from what I have remarked is that the compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: I'd like you to tell me why you are ignoring my advice.  Since you have access to the source code for the entire codebase, you can change the relevant class to allow you to do what you want.  Why don't you do that?